# What does API means on the insight, Where Your Page Likes Happened?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-insights

I'd like to ask how it can be counted as API on like source of "Where Your Page Likes Happened" on the page insight as attached, not about API itself.

What kind of action does the users counted as API of like source do to like?

[image]

[image]

[>Page>Insights>Likes>Where Your Likes Happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTx6g.png)
[API as one of like source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRSQP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Likes from "API" refers to Apps that use graphAPI or SDK , mainly 3rd party likes.

The most common examples of apps that will be counted as "API" here are Facebook users using "Snaptu" or "Facebook Lite". While I agree its kind of weird that these are considered "API" likes, it makes sense due to the way these are implemented.